# ImageView is not displayed in bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

```
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mViewer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rcviewer, null);
    setContentView(mViewer);

    mViewerTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewer_title);
    mViewerBody = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewer_body);
    mViewerPage= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewer_page);
    mImgBookmark = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.viewer_bookmark);
    mImgBookmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
...

public Bitmap getCurrentPage() {
    Bitmap tmpBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDisplay.getWidth(), mDisplay.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    tmpBitmap.eraseColor(0xffffffff);

    if (isBookmarked()) {
        mImgBookmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        mImgBookmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    mViewerTitle.setText(mPage.getTitle());
    mViewerBody.setText(mPage.getContent());
    mViewerPage.setText(mPage.getPage());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tmpBitmap);
    mViewer.draw(canvas);

    return tmpBitmap;
}
```

Although 'isBookmarked()' is true, 'mImgBookmark' is not displayed in tmpBitmap.
mViewerTitle, mViewerBody, mViewerPage is displayed in tmpBitmap.

I want to display 'mImgBookmark' image in tmpBitmap. 
I don't know what to do.
what should I do ?

Thank you.

Comment: you have not set ImageViewbackground anywhere.So its not showing any background.In text view you have setText() but not imageview

Comment: btw can you see the `mImgBookmark` on screen after you call `setContentView`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 mImgBookmark = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.viewer_bookmark);
    mImgBookmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//Sets a Bitmap as the content of this ImageView.
mImgBookmark.setImageBitmap(getCurrentPage())
```